# getCoordinates() function return wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have code to create and modify features in the Openlayers map. but when extract coordinates from features with getCoordinates() function it returns the wrong coordinates. when  I try to search the coordinates in Google Maps, Google Maps can't find the location.

here my code:

```
var raster = new TileLayer({
       source: new OSM()
      });
var source = new VectorSource({ wrapX: false });
var vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: source,
      renderBuffer: 600,
      style: new Style({
fill: new Fill({ 
     color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
     }), 
stroke: new Stroke({
  color: "#ffcc33",
  width: 3
}),
image: new CircleStyle({
  radius: 7,
  fill: new Fill({
    color: "#ffcc33"})})})});
   var map = new Map({
     layers: [raster, vector],
     target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 1
  })
});

 var modify = new Modify({ source: source });
 map.addInteraction(modify);

var draw, snap; // global so we can remove them later
var typeSelect = document.getElementById("type");
function addInteractions() {
 draw = new Draw({
  source: source,
  type: typeSelect.value,

 });

 map.addInteraction(draw);
 snap = new Snap({ source: source });
 map.addInteraction(snap);
 }
  
 

  const getData = document.getElementById("getData");
  getData.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const format = new GeoJSON({ featureProjection: "EPSG:3857" });
  var features = source.getFeatures();
  var json = format.writeFeatures(features);
  console.log(json);

  });

    /**
    * Handle change event.
    */
  typeSelect.onchange = function () {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  map.removeInteraction(snap);
  addInteractions();
   };

addInteractions();
```

and the example of the results

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates": 
  [-239.94578665160495,-5.404682369862513]},"properties":null},{"type":"Feature","geometry": 
 {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-247.41559088929245,-7.170282449846823]},"properties":null}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Longitude values less than -180 or greater than +180 are useful to indicate that linetrings and polygons have been drawn across the dateline, but are less useful for Point geometry, so you could normalise their coordinates:

```
source.on('addfeature', function(event){
  var geometry = event.feature.getGeometry();
  if (geometry.getType() === 'Point') {
    geometry.setCoordinates(fromLonLat(toLonLat(geometry.getCoordinates())));
  }
});
```